# I would like to eliminate 2 3-way switches on one circuit

Tags: wiring

I have 2 3-way switches operating the electrical plugs (No lights) in the living room. I would like to eliminate both switches so the plugs are on all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to leave at least one receptacle controlled by the switches, or you'd be violating 210.70(A)(1).

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 2 Wiring and Protection
>
> #### Article 210 Branch Circuits
>
> **210.70 Lighting Outlets Required.**
>
> **(A) Dwelling Units.**
>
> **(1) Habitable Rooms.** At least one wall switch controlled lighting outlet shall be installed in every habitable room and bathroom.

If you want to know how to rewire the other receptacles, you're going to have to include a bit of information on how they're currently wired.  Turn off the breaker, pull out the receptacles (leaving the wires attached), and document the wires and how they're connected.